# How do I recreate the scroll effect on http://www.chanel.com

Tags: jquery

Good day everyone.

My client requires that I recreate the scroll effect seen on [Chanel](http://www.chanel.com).
I have an understanding of html & CSS but am still relatively new to Jquery.

How do i go about hiding the slideshow and revealing the content when the user scrolls down, and vice versa?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using the plugin found at https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    var top = delta > 0 ? 0 : '90%';
    $('.blue').stop().animate({top:top});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/bn75Q/)

Comment: Thanks Spokey, you have been a tremendous help!